# How Do I create a MSI which runs without Admin priviledge

Tags: admin, installshield

I need to create an installer which can be downloaded from net and installed without any Admin rights.

I've Created a "Install Shield MSI Project" . In Release Wizard I've chosen

```
Media Type -> Web,
Web Type -> Install From The web,  
one .cab per component,
Checked One Click Install,
```

In Release tab 
     Setup I've chosen
     Required execution level ->    Invoker,
    Advertise If Prerequisite are elevated -> Adversite:silent,
    InstallShield Prerequisite location -> Download from web,

Generate One Click Install ->Yes,

In property Manager I've set

### ALLUSERS=2 and  MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1

I'm able to download the installer and can install it but it asks for Admin password.
How can I remove this UAC?

Answer (score 3):

The settings related to prerequisites will not help here; at best the advertising helps avoid a second UAC prompt, but that's only if there was a first one.

The properties `ALLUSERS` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER` are for conditionally per-user installations. For an installation that is always per-user, you are better off specifying **Require Administrative Privileges=No** in the General Information view, in the Summary Information Stream section. This will prevent the UAC prompt.

Note that this setting will cause the installation to fail if it actually requires any administrative access.

Comment: I've Created a InstallScript project which does not have Summary Information Stream section so how do I set Require Administrative Privileges=No

Comment: InstallScript projects never prompt for elevation in the middle, so the advice is almost reversed: only the setup.exe setting matters to the behavior, and only the project's contents (don't do anything that requires administrative privilege) dictate whether that will succeed.